# Jquery UI multicolumn autocomplete change event is not triggered

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, custom-formatting

I am using jquery-ui autocomplete with multicolumn using **_renderMenu** and **_renderItem** as per [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4stL/212/)

```
$.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
_renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
    var self = this,
        thead;

    if (this.options.showHeader) {
        table = $('<div class="ui-widget-header" style="width:100%"></div>');
        $.each(this.options.columns, function(index, item) {
            table.append('<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + item.width + ';">' + item.name + '</span>');
        });
        table.append('<div style="clear: both;"></div>');
        ul.append(table);
    }
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        self._renderItem(ul, item);
    });
},
_renderItem: function(ul, item) {
    var t = '',
        result = '';

    $.each(this.options.columns, function(index, column) {
        t += '<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + column.width + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
    });

    result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
    return result;
}
});
```

Change event is triggered if I click outside of autocomplete without selecting any result.

But change event is not triggered when clicking on header(column) and then clicking on outside.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the exact same one. it seems that ui.item: undefined. in addition as you can see from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CFL4/) it doesn't work in jquery ui 1.10 but [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/g4stL/212/) in jquery 1.8.18

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem, jquery changed the key by which autocomplete saves the item data  from 'item.autocomplete' to 'ui-autocomplete-item' so the fix is to change your line:

```
result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
```

to

```
result = $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle using jquery 1.10](http://jsfiddle.net/crashandburn4/J4D6t/2/)